# Multiple tag labels for the same tag

Tags: support, tags

I just looked at the list of tags for Stack Overflow and jumped all the way to the last page. I started looking through the different ones and found two labels for the exact same tag, though they were named differently in the labels.

They link to the exact same page, and the previews of them are equal. When clicking on `Watch Tag` for one, the change is reflected in the preview for the other one.

[image]

Is this a bug? I assume tags should only have one label. In that case, one of the labels (not [the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework?tab=Newest)) should be removed. [`zend`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework?tab=Newest) Is the most clearly written, and is what I'd say is the most descriptive name, but the existence of [`zf2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework2?tab=Newest) is a reason to rather keep [`zf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework?tab=Newest).

I just saw that [`zencoding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zencoding) and [`zen-coding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zencoding), as seen in the image, also point to the exact same tag (not `zf`).

Comment: Look at `Synonyms` on the right hand side.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Aha...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug. As Gerardo mentions in the comments, they are synonyms. You can see the entire list of Synonyms on this page https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms.

For specific tags you can click on "Synonyms (x)" in the tag description. The number (x) in the brackets indicates the number of synonyms that a tag has. For example, the [zen-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zen-coding) tag, which you pointed out, is a synonym of [emmet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emmet), which has 3 synonyms. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/emmet/synonyms.

The tags on the tag page are mentioned separately, so that users can easily find them. For example, I didn't know that zen-coding was renamed as emmet, and therefore I can search for zen-coding, and still arrive at the tag. The same is the situation when adding a tag to a post.